# What's the best way to install command line utilities such as GIT?

Tags: macos, command-line, macports, homebrew

I'm a Windows/Linux guy that just got my Macbook Air. I do web dev, and am currently trying to setup this machine for some on-the-go development.

After some research attempts, I'm wondering: what's the best way to install command line utilities in Lion, such as GIT? Best as in easiest to install, maintain, upgrade etc.

As I understand it, there are some alternatives: macports, homebrew etc. Or in the GIT example, maybe just download the installer from their website.

Thanks.

Comment: Install all CLI that support it with homebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how many tools/libraries you need to install.

If just git then use Xcode 4 which you will need for any port package. If you are doing pure HTML/Javascripy/CSS then the git installer will work.

For python and perl and similar interpreters the the language install tools can be used unless there are complex C/C++ libraries

If only a few others then build into /usr/local

However if you have several things to install or there are complex dependencies then I would use a ports package like Fink, macports or homebrew (which is best is debatable and should be a separate discussion)

Comment: To answer your follow up: I will also need to install apache, php, mysql, node.js, maybe python etc. Xcode's 3 GB foot print seams a little rough, since I currently only would need it for GIT.

Comment: Given this question for python and mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x/1448446#1448446 - I suspect you will need a ports system and they require Xcode

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've installed brew now, so will try if it is sufficient, otherwise I'll check out macports.

Answer (score 2):

Git's bundled with the free version of [Xcode 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20170401072804/https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) on the app store. That's about as easy and official as it gets in my book. You won't do wrong by choosing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as it's solid and got great momentum plus mindshare presently.

Comment: Thanks. The 3 GB foot print of Xcode is a little daunting, since I currently only would need it for GIT. Do you know if there are any other CLI tools bundled with Xcode?

Comment: clang, llvm, and tons of other tools (but no db nor node.js). Start with homebrew and grab the Xcode next time you're in an Apple store or other place with a fast pipe and a USB drive in your pocket.

Comment: I think it comes with the Xcode Command Line Tools, which is a smaller download than the Xcode app.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just git then, by all means, their installation procedure works well. But you know it won't stay like that.

I really prefer homebrew over macports. I brew everyday =) It's super easy to install: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation
And it hasn't bitten me yet. Their non-sudo approach rocks. Maybe there aren't always formulas for everything, but I most often take that as a hint. =)

Comment: Thanks. Any specific reason you prefer homebrew?

Comment: I find it much less prone to end up in a dependency mess than macports. With Macports I often found myself with a broken package which could steal hours from time I didn't have. I'm sure it depended a lot on me, but homebrew just treats me nicer. It's super fast too.

Comment: With macports and fink everything is not in /usr/local so is sandboxed away from the standard compilers so is more repeatable (and I have not found many broken packages and with Unix security it is better to install as a different user to yourself) - note this is why I suggest macports vs fink vs homebrew discussions are not really part of the answer to this question